# Create a custom filter with two filters in the same column with Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to create a custom filter but one that takes into account two filter sat the same time with primefaces (cf https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) .

I need to filter by grade as followed and therefore I need two filters:
[image]

But of course the function filter can receive only one filter as followed 
`public boolean filterByNote(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale)`

So I had the idea to counter that by creating two attributes in my class and use them in the method. But it failed because (I think the reason is that) the onchange attribute of the tag p:selectOneButton is not called anymore. If I suppress one of the p:selectOne**** it works (not as expected because only one filter is applied but I can see change) therefore I know the other part of the code is working.

So my question is, is there a way to use two filters as I need ?

```js
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class StatFilter implements Serializable {
 private int signNote;
 private int note;

 private List<Formulaire> formulaireComplete;
 private List<Formulaire> formulaireFiltre;


 // Filter by Note in a Form
 public boolean filterByNote(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
  List<Reponse> resp = (List<Reponse>) value;
  // if reset, display all
  System.out.println("something"); // to check if the function is called
  if (signNote == 0)
   return true;
  // if at list one of the note is ...
  // ...superior to the attribute note
  else if (signNote == 1) {
   for (int i = 0; i < resp.size(); i++) {
    if (resp.get(i).getNote() > this.note)
     return true;
   }
  }
  // ...inferior to the attribute note
  else if (signNote == 2) {
   for (int i = 0; i < resp.size(); i++) {
    if (resp.get(i).getNote() < this.note)
     return true;
   }
  }
  // ...equal to the attribute note
  else if (signNote == 3) {
   for (int i = 0; i < resp.size(); i++) {
    if (resp.get(i).getNote() == this.note)
     return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

}
```

```html
<p:column filterBy="#{formulaire.reponses}" headerText="Note"
 footerText="equals" filterFunction="#{statFilter.filterByNote}">
 <f:facet name="filter">
  <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('formulairesTable').filter()" value="#{statFilter.signNote}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reset" itemValue="0" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="&gt;" itemValue="1" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;" itemValue="2" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="=" itemValue="3" />
  </p:selectOneButton>
           <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('formulairesTable').filter()" value="#{statFilter.note}"> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "1" itemLabel = "1" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "2" itemLabel = "2" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "3" itemLabel = "3" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "4" itemLabel = "4" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "5" itemLabel = "5" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "6" itemLabel = "6" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "7" itemLabel = "7" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "8" itemLabel = "8" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "9" itemLabel = "9" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "10" itemLabel = "10" /> 
      <f:selectItem itemValue = "0" itemLabel = "NA" /> 
  </p:selectOneMenu>
 </f:facet>
 <h:outputText value="#{formulaire.responsesToString()}" escape="false" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: I think (never tried) you need a composite component for this with a backing bean and making sure the value object is a composite, containing both values... See http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html

Comment: I will try to do so and if it works I'll post the solution, thanks @Kukeltje !